# Slow performance on HP DC7800 SFF desktop

Tags: hardware, performance, drivers

I have installed latest Ubuntu 64 bit on the hp dc7800 with core 2 duo e6550.

It has 2gb ram. Not a stellar machine, but I'm getting very poor performance.

Windows and applications are slow to open and move.

Checked drivers and it says "no propietary drivers" are installed.

I just flattened and re-installed the 32-bit, as read somewhere that 2Gb is bare minimum for a 64-bit install. 32-bit seems the same symptoms.

What can I do to diagnose and rectify the sluggish performance?

Comment: The graphics chip in this PC seems to be hit by a nasty bug: [LP Bug #931122](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/931122). Make sure you subscribe to the bug report and mark yourself as affected! I'm now voting-to-close your question as bugs are off-topic here on this site, per the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). See [this very similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/244255/88802) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is in your question "Checked drivers and it says "no propietary drivers" are installed". Thats were I would start.

**To install the drivers**

> Go to **System Settings**
>
> Select **"Additional Drivers"**
>
> Install the Recommended Video driver.

If there are no drivers available check what Video card you have.  Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) then paste

> spci | grep -i pci || lspci

then

> sudo lshw

When you know what video driver you have, search other questions at AU for related issues.  I tried to google myself but wasnt successful. Im not sure if being an SFF desktop has any bearing.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, it doesn't let me click anything within, just an empty panel with no additional drivers offered.

Comment: I updated ny answer to help you further

Comment: Looks like I have `Intel Corporation 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)`

Comment: Thanks for your help - a quick Google around shows that there's no closed-source Linux drivers with 3D acceleration (which would presumably make the desktop much snappier). Also others are reporting sluggish performance as well as artifacts and corruption like me. Might sell this box and get another, better-linux-supported one.